# MySQL won't start or won't installed

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm trying to get a local LAMP setup on my Ubuntu desktop. I'm successfully got PHP install but I'm having trouble with MySQL

If PHP tries to connet to MySQL I get this error:
`Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /var/www/testing.php on line 3
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

If I try via command line I get much the same error:
`owen@desktop:~$ mysql

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)`

Weirdly "/var/run/mysqld" does not exist.

Running a whereis command I get the following:
`owen@desktop:~$ whereis mysqld.sock

mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld /usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz`

So is MySQL even installed? Well acording to dpkg
`owen@desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep mysql

ii  libapache2-mod-auth-mysql                                4.3.9-13ubuntu1                                   Apache 2 module for MySQL authentication

ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                                        4.016-1                                           Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database

ii  libmysqlclient15off                                      5.1.30really5.0.83-0ubuntu3                       MySQL database client library

ii  libmysqlclient16                                         5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database client library

ii  mysql-admin                                              5.0r14+openSUSE-2.1                               GUI tool for intuitive MySQL administration

ii  mysql-client-5.1                                         5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database client binaries

ii  mysql-client-core-5.1                                    5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database core client binaries

ii  mysql-common                                             5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf

ii  mysql-gui-tools-common                                   5.0r14+openSUSE-2.1                               Architecture independent files for MySQL GUI Tools

ii  mysql-query-browser                                      5.0r14+openSUSE-2.1                               Official GUI tool to query MySQL database

ii  mysql-server                                             5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)

ii  mysql-server-5.1                                         5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

ii  mysql-server-core-5.0                                    5.1.30really5.0.83-0ubuntu3                       MySQL database core server files

ii  mysql-server-core-5.1                                    5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                 MySQL database server binaries

ii  php5-mysql`

Can someone please help I'm really confused as what to do next. I'm not a Linux expert at all most of these commands I've ran I found of diffrent blogs and help forums.

Comment: Apparently your mysql server is not running. Use `/etc/init.d/mysql-server start` and check your log `tail -f /var/log/syslog` for any errors on the startup process.

Comment: netstat -tupln | grep 3306

Comment: Run the above comment and it will identify if mysql is listening on it's standard port.

Comment: owen@desktop:~$ /etc/init.d/mysql-server start
bash: /etc/init.d/mysql-server: No such file or directory

Comment: owen@desktop:~$ netstat -tupln | grep 3306  
(Not all processes can be identified, no information of ownership of the process not show, to be root to see them all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I finally got MySQL working by running the commands I found on a similar forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1373144

`sudo mysql_install_db`

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1`

Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Sounds like you're doing something like.....

```
mysql_connect('localhost'....
```

The mysql client lib, when it sees 'localhost' doesn't bother making a network conection - it uses the local file (unix) socket. In order to find this socket, it should check the php.ini setting, or use the value in my.cnf, or failing these, compiled in default(s).

Check the mysql is running

```
ps auxwww | grep mysqld
```

Check its listening on a network socket:

```
netstats -nap
```

The above should also show what file socket it is listening on.

Assuming this is a default installation (i.e. listening on the network port and with no root password) You should be able to connect to the network socket using

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
```

Then 
    show variables like '%sock%'

will also show you where the filesystem socket is.

Update your php.ini setting, e.g.

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and restart your webserver.

Comment: It seems to be running:
owen@desktop:~$ ps auxwww | grep mysqld
owen      2434  0.0  0.0  11348   868 pts/0    S+   15:03   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld

Comment: I now think that somehow my installation of MySQL has been corrupted or failed, how can I uninstall & reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my box.
Try running `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` to connect via tcp/ip instead of socket.

Comment: owen@desktop:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1  
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: When PHP tries to connect using 127.0.0.1 I get this diffrent error message: 
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in /var/www/testing.php on line 3
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111